# Copy input file, binary and ASCII files to new file

Tags: c

I just started learning C a little bit ago and I need help with a particular program. I need to read lines from a file (about 50 bytes at a time) and copy them over to a new file, including binary files. It's pretty simple but I'm having trouble on how exactly I should go about doing it. So far I have

```
 while ( ) {
    read (infile, buffer, 50);
    if (r< 0) {
            perror("cannot read infile");
            exit (-1);
    }
    if (r==0) {
            break;
    }
    write (outfile, buffer, r);
    }
```

while I already open and close the files I will need. The loop should read the file 50 bytes at a time and write them to a new file, but I'm not sure what the condition of the while loop should be. I was thinking maybe taking the number of bytes in the file and make it so it will loop through the file as long as there are more bytes left. However, I am not entirely sure how to do that. Any help in the right direction?

Comment: how did you open the file?

Comment: In fact you must open the file in binary mode to get the result you are after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the return value of `read`:

```
r = read (infile, buffer, 50);
```

Given how the loop is set up, you could use the always-true condition: `while(1)` (since you already break when you reach the end of the file)

Answer (score 2):

```
while (1) {
    int r = read (infile, buffer, 50);
    if (r< 0) {
            perror("cannot read infile");
            exit (-1);
    }
    if (r==0) {
            break;
    }
    if(write (outfile, buffer, r) != r)
            printf("write error\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can change (r == 0) to (r < 50) because the last line probably won't be a full 50 bytes.  If it is, the next run through will be 0 anyway, which will still evaluate to true.  And you never actually capture r as a return value from read().

For your actual question, you could do it in a variety of ways.  Currently, you could write

```
while(1){

    r = read(infile, buffer, 50);

    if ( r < 50) {
    ...
    break;
    }
}
```

will work just fine.  The break statement will exit the loop when the r < 50 condition is satisfied, implying no bytes were read.

For code that is more clear and readable, you could use an int as a boolean like this:

```
int FileDone = 0;
while(!FileDone){        
    ...
    if ( r < 50) {
        FileDone = 1
    }
}
```

or maybe like this:

```
int r = 1;
while (r > 0){

    r = read(infile, buffer, 50);

    if (r < 0) {
        perror("cannot read infile");
        exit (-1);
    }

    write (outfile, buffer, r);
}
```